# Navigating Screens in Flutter based on if it's new sign in or returning user

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

After sign up, I want the user to be taken to WelcomeScreen() and after sign in, to Sessions(). However, with the way my root page is currently structured, it's a bit hard to achieved.

How can I do this? See code snippets and explanations below.

In my main.dart file, my RootPage is set to be the initialRoute. The RootPage checks if there's a valid session and thus redirects to PaymentScreen, else of redirects to Sessions.dart which handles the sign in and sign out views.

```
//root_page.dart
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class RootPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'root_page';

  Widget buildWaitingScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // ignore: missing_return
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BaseAuth auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool isLoggedIn = snapshot.hasData;

          return isLoggedIn ? WelcomeEmail() : Sessions();
//          return isLoggedIn ? PaymentScreen() : Sessions();
        }
        return buildWaitingScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My AuthProvider...

```
class AuthProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  AuthProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.auth,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(auth != null),
        assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final BaseAuth auth;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AuthProvider old) => auth != old.auth;

  //this static class allows us to access AuthProvider anywhere in our code using AuthProvider.of(context).auth
  static AuthProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AuthProvider>();
  }
}
```

My auth.dart

```
abstract class BaseAuth {
  Stream<User> get user;
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged;
  Future<String> handleSignIn(String email, String password);
  Future<String> handleSignUp(String email, String password);
  Future<String> currentUser();
}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create a new user object based on FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  @override
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map((user) => user?.uid);
  }

  //sign in with email and password
  Future<String> handleSignIn(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .catchError((error) => print(error));

    if (result != null) {
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      if (user != null) {
        print('From handleSignIn, Log in: ${user.email}');
      }
      return user.uid;
    }
  }

  //sign up with email and password
  Future<String> handleSignUp(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .catchError((error) => print(error));
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    if (user != null) {
      print('From handleSignUp, New user email: ${user.email}');
    }

    return user.uid;
  }
}
```

My sessions.dart file

```
class Sessions extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'sessions';

  @override
  _SessionsState createState() => _SessionsState();
}

enum SessionType { signIn, signUp, reset }

class _SessionsState extends State<Sessions> {
  String email, password, _warning;

  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var args;

  SessionType _sessionType = SessionType.signIn;

  setArguments(args) async {
    _sessionType = args[0];
  }

  //validate form fields input and save
  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      print('form is valid, Email: $email, Password: $password');
      return true;
    } else {
      print('form is invalid');
      return false;
    }
  }

  //remove extra spacing before and after input text
  String trimTextInput(String value) {
    return value.toString().trim();
  }

  //validate form and sign in / sign up
  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = true;
      });
      try {
        final BaseAuth auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
        if (_sessionType == SessionType.signIn) {
          String user = await auth.handleSignIn(
              trimTextInput(email), trimTextInput(password));
          print('Signed in: $user');

          if (user == null) {
            setState(() {
              showSpinner = false;
              _warning = 'could not sign in with those credentials';
            });
          }
        } else if (_sessionType == SessionType.reset) {
          print('password reset email sent to $email');
          await auth
              .sendPasswordResetEmail(trimTextInput(email))
              .catchError((onError) => print(onError));
          _warning = 'A password reset link has been sent to $email';
          setState(() {
            showSpinner = false;
            _sessionType = SessionType.signIn;
          });
        } else {
          String user = await auth.handleSignUp(
              trimTextInput(email), trimTextInput(password));
          print('Signed up: $user');
          if (user == null) {
            setState(() {
              showSpinner = false;
              _warning = 'could not sign up with those credentials';
            });
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Warning message: ${e.toString()}');
      }
    }
  }

  //toggle to switch between sign up and sign in views
  void toggleFormView(String state) {
    _formKey.currentState.reset();
    if (state == 'signUp') {
      setState(() {
        _sessionType = SessionType.signUp;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _sessionType = SessionType.signIn;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      setState(() {
        args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      });
      // _sessionType = args.sessionType;
      print('Session type: $_sessionType');
      // setArguments(args);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ModalProgressHUD(
          inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                showAlert(),
                buildHeaderText(_warning, 3, kHeading1TextStyle),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Flexible(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: 'logo',
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 7.0),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: buildInputFields() + submitButtons(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showAlert() {
    if (_warning != null) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: warningText(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _warning = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }

  Widget warningText() {
    return Text(
      _warning,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: kRegularTextStyle,
      maxLines: 3,
    );
  }

  Widget buildHeaderText(String headerText, int maxLines, TextStyle style) {
    if (_sessionType == SessionType.signUp) {
      headerText = "Create New Account";
    } else if (_sessionType == SessionType.reset) {
      headerText = "Reset Password";
    } else {
      headerText = "Sign In";
    }
    return Text(
      headerText,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: style,
      maxLines: maxLines,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildInputFields() {
    if (_sessionType == SessionType.reset) {
      return [
        TextFormField(
          key: Key('email'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          onSaved: (value) => email = value,
          validator: EmailFieldValidator.validate,
          decoration:
              kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'enter your email'),
        ),
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        TextFormField(
          key: Key('email'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          onSaved: (value) => email = value,
          validator: EmailFieldValidator.validate,
          decoration:
              kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'enter your email'),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
        TextFormField(
          key: Key('password'),
          obscureText: true,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          validator: PasswordFieldValidator.validate,
          onSaved: (value) => password = value,
          decoration:
              kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'enter your password'),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      ];
    }
  }

  List<Widget> submitButtons() {
    bool _showForgotPassword = false;

    if (_sessionType == SessionType.signIn) {
      _showForgotPassword = true;
      return [
        Buttons(
          key: Key('signIn'),
          buttonLabel: 'Sign In',
          buttonColour: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
          buttonTextStyle: kThemeStyleButton,
          onPressedButton: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
        showForgotPassword(_showForgotPassword),
        PaddedClickableText(
          myText: 'Don\'t have an account? Sign up now',
          onTap: () => toggleFormView('signUp'),
        ),
      ];
    } else if (_sessionType == SessionType.reset) {
      return [
        Buttons(
          key: Key('submit'),
          buttonLabel: 'Submit',
          buttonColour: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
          buttonTextStyle: kThemeStyleButton,
          onPressedButton: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
        PaddedClickableText(
          myText: 'Return back to sign in',
          onTap: () => toggleFormView('signIn'),
        ),
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        Buttons(
          key: Key('signUp'),
          buttonLabel: 'Sign Up',
          buttonColour: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
          buttonTextStyle: kThemeStyleButton,
          onPressedButton: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
        PaddedClickableText(
          myText: 'Already have an account? Sign in here',
          onTap: () => toggleFormView('signIn'),
        ),
      ];
    }
  }

  Widget showForgotPassword(bool visible) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: visible,
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _sessionType = SessionType.reset;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          'Forgot password?',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: kThemeTextColour,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EmailFieldValidator {
  static String validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null;
  }
}

class PasswordFieldValidator {
  static String validate(String value) {
    return value.length < 6 || value.isEmpty
        ? 'Password can\'t be empty'
        : null;
  }
}

class SessionsArguments {
  final SessionType sessionType;

  SessionsArguments(this.sessionType);
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing with the approach you have taken?

Comment: The issue is, I'm trying to navigate the user (if its a new sign up) to the welcome screen, whilst if its an returning user (sign in action), I navigate them to the PaymentScreen()

What I've tried is as above.

Comment: For emphasis, I'm trying to detect where a signed in user is navigating from in my root page and be able to navigate them to either WelcomeScreen() if SignUp and PaymentScreen() if SignIn.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, people use Shared Prefs for storing basic login information,
So that the next time a person opens the Application you can just use that information to route to whichever way you want.

Another way would be to use a variable. If they signUp then set that variable to true and route to a different page.

Do let me know if you need code snippets for each.

Comment: Hi Ayush, that thought line of declaring a variable makes sense. 
I haven't explored SharedPreferences.
And yes please, I'd love to see code snippets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Ayush said, you can use SharedPreferences to check if a user is returned or not.

To do this, first you need to install `shared_preferences` package.
Installation is simple: Open pubspec.yaml file, add this line `shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4` (this is the latest version as I write this answer) under `dependencies` section and run `flutter pub get`.

A basic example:

```
// Import shared_preferences library  
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// Save the isLoggedIn data when user is logged in to system
saveLoggedIn() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);
}

// Get the isLoggedIn data to check if user is returned
getLoggedIn() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool isUserLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
  return isUserLoggedIn;
}
```

Comment: HI harundemir918, thanks for the code snippet. How exactly does it differ from what I have above? Unless I'm getting it wrong it does the same thing my auth.onAuthStateChanged does.

Also, it doesn't solve the problem of me wanting to know if user is returning or new user.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is like a little local database where you can store simple data like int, bool etc. I'm using it in one of my projects. It works like this: When user launches app for the first time, app checks if there are `loggedIn` data in `SharedPreferences`. Because it is the first time of launching, there is no data. Then app redirects to login page. After user logs into his account, app goes and saves a `loggedIn` data to `SharedPreferences`. It can be bool, int etc. After user closes and opens the app again, app goes and finds the `loggedIn` data, then redirects to user page.